# Pause protractor script while a class is present?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying make sure that the protractor test cannot continue while a class is present in my angular app. The class is responsible for locking the ui with a high z-index so the user wouldn't be able to click anything. I want to simulate this in my test. However, I'm not having any luck with this code:

```
    // Wait http commands to finish
    browser.wait(function() {
        console.log(element(by.className('is-fetchingData')).isPresent());
        return element(by.className('is-fetchingData')).isPresent()
    }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.wait(function() {
    return element(by.className('is-fetchingData')).isPresent().
           then(function(isPresent){
                   console.log("Is Element Present? - "+isPresent);
                   if(isPresent){
                       return true;
                   }   
           });
},'element is not present till timeout reached', 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using expected condtions, Look at below example

```
var ele = element(by.className('is-fetchingData'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element  to be no longer visible on the dom.
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(ele), 5000); //this will wait untill the element is disappeared from the page.
```